# AWS S3 : Spark - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute... while saving dataframe to s3 location as json

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, dataframe, amazon-s3

I am getting strange error while saving dataframe to AWS S3.

```
 df.coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .json(s"s3://myawsacc/results/")
```

---

In the same location I was able to insert the data from spark-shell . 
and is working...

```
 spark.sparkContext.parallelize(1 to 4).toDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
          .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
          .save(s"s3://myawsacc/results/")
```

> My question is why its working in spark-shell and is not working via
>   spark-submit ? Is there any logic/properties/configuration for this?

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3Credentials.initialize(S3Credentials.java:45)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.HadoopConfigurationAWSCredentialsProvider.(HadoopConfigurationAWSCredentialsProvider.java:26)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.guice.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderFactory.getAwsCredentialsProviderChain(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderFactory.java:44)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.guice.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderFactory.getAwsCredentialsProvider(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderFactory.java:28)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.guice.EmrFSProdModule.getAwsCredentialsProvider(EmrFSProdModule.java:70)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.guice.EmrFSProdModule.createS3Configuration(EmrFSProdModule.java:86)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.guice.EmrFSProdModule.createAmazonS3LiteClient(EmrFSProdModule.java:80)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.guice.EmrFSProdModule.createAmazonS3Lite(EmrFSProdModule.java:120)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.guice.EmrFSBaseModule.provideAmazonS3Lite(EmrFSBaseModule.java:99)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:104)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.inject(SingleFieldInjector.java:53)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:110)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:94)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
       at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.initialize(EmrFileSystem.java:103)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2717)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:93)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2751)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2733)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:377)
       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:394)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:471)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:50)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:609)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:217)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.json(DataFrameWriter.scala:487)
       at com.org.ComparatorUtil$.writeLogNError(ComparatorUtil.scala:245)
       at com.org.ComparatorUtil$.writeToJson(ComparatorUtil.scala:161)
       at com.org.comparator.SnowFlakeTableComparator$.mainExecutor(SnowFlakeTableComparator.scala:98)
       at com.org.executor.myclass$$anonfun$main$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(myclass.scala:232)
       at com.org.executor.myclass$$anonfun$main$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(myclass.scala:153)
       at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
       at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
       at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
       at com.org.executor.myclass$$anonfun$main$4.apply(myclass.scala:153)
       at com.org.executor.myclass$$anonfun$main$4.apply(myclass.scala:134)
       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
       at com.org.executor.myclass$.main(myclass.scala:134)
       at com.org.executor.myclass.main(myclass.scala)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:775)
       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
           at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1088)
           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.http.AbstractHttpFileSystem.open(AbstractHttpFileSystem.java:60)
           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.http.HttpFileSystem.open(HttpFileSystem.java:23)
           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:773)
           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsUrlConnection.connect(FsUrlConnection.java:50)
           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsUrlConnection.getInputStream(FsUrlConnection.java:59)
           at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
           at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory._optimizedStreamFromURL(JsonFactory.java:1479)
           at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:779)
           at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2679)
           at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.PlatformInfo.getClusterIdFromConfigurationEndpoint(PlatformInfo.java:39)
           at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.PlatformInfo.getJobFlowId(PlatformInfo.java:53)
           at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.EmrFsUtils.getJobFlowId(EmrFsUtils.java:384)
           at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.EmrFsUtils.(EmrFsUtils.java:60)
           ... 77 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.net.URI

import spark.implicits._

    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(1 to 4).toDF
      .coalesce(1)
      .write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .json(new URI("s3://myawsacc/results/").toString)

    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(1 to 4).toDF
      .coalesce(1)
      .write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .json(URI.create("s3://myawsacc/results/").toString)
```

is working fine for me.

seems like spark-shell implcitly applying `new URI` or `URI.create` and hence its was working fine.

Comment: I am using pyspark , I am getting same issue with spark-submit however it works fine with spark-shell. In my case    ..  df = spark.read.option("basePath", base_path).schema(schema).orc(s3_path)  , here base path is : s3://data-lake/staging/scoring/cust and s3_path is list paths like  .orc(['s3://data-lake/staging/scoring/cust/1/2','s3://data-lake/staging/scoring/cust/2/3','s3://data-lake/staging/scoring/cust/4/5'])   how i can handle this to convert programmatically to URI conversion @Ram appreciate if you can help here